# Colour top row (header row) regardless of number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and thus this might be an easy one. I'm trying to colour the top row of any workbook regardless of the amount or columns. I would obviously like the colour to stop with the last column.

The colour isn't too important as I can change it in the code once figured out.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Interior.Color = vbGreen`  or maybe just `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen`

Comment: It is clear if the used range is `A1:J10` that you want to highlight `A1:J1`. But what do you want to highlight if the used range is `C3:J10`: `A1:J1`, `A3:J3`, `C1:J1`, or `C3:J3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a surprising proposal:

```
Rows("1:1").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))"
Rows("1:1").FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Rows("1:1").FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Rows("1:1").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

(This is more or less the result of the macro recorder, some things might be obsolete.)

In order to obtain this, I used conditional formatting, based on the formula "`=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))`". In other words: when something gets written in that cell, the cell gets a background colour.

I've used this approach as you mentioned "regardless of the number of columns". The other answers start with a certain amount of columns but if you add one, you need to run their macro again. My solution does not need that.

Comment: this one is magnificent! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder can help us a lot to start going with vba.

I have recorded a macro were I have selecetd the top row of a worksheet, and changed its color. This is what i've got

```
Sub Color()
'
' Color Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092441
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Now there are some definitions here that might or may not interest you.

A simpler code to have the row gray using RGB:

```
Sub Color()
'
' Color Macro
'
    
    With Rows("1:1").Interior
        .Color = RGB(215, 215, 215)

    End With
End Sub
```